CORS in strapi v4.24.2 doesn't work anymore
i'm trying to add CORS for some of my sub-domains/domains such that only those will be able to access my strapi resources but unfortunately i'm unable to do so. I followed the documentation as per https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/configurations/middlewares, still no luck, I can still access strapi backend through any domain (currently testing with http://localhost:3000/ - my nextjs project (strapi running on http://localhost:1337)). I tried adding @koa/cors and added in resolutions as well but still no luck. Below are some details about the project and some related code ;-
package.json
{
  "name": "blog",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": {
    "name": "A Strapi developer"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "strapi build",
    "dev": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "strapi": "strapi"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@koa/cors": "3.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@_sh/strapi-plugin-ckeditor": "^1.1.1",
    "@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager": "^3.480.0",
    "@koa/cors": "3.4.1",
    "@strapi/plugin-color-picker": "^4.9.1",
    "@strapi/plugin-graphql": "^4.25.2",
    "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.25.2",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.25.2",
    "@strapi/provider-upload-aws-s3": "^4.25.2",
    "@strapi/strapi": "4.25.2",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.11"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12.x.x <=16.x.x",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "ba9d89a9-e1d5-417e-acbf-c71785f9086f"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ajv": "^8.16.0"
  }
}

config/middlewares.js
module.exports = ({ env }) => {
  return [
    "strapi::errors",
    "strapi::security",
    "strapi::poweredBy",
    {
      name: "strapi::cors",
      config: {
        origin: env.array("CORS"),
        methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"],
        headers: ["Content-Type", "Authorization", "Origin", "Accept"],
        keepHeaderOnError: true,
      },
    },
    "strapi::logger",
    "strapi::query",
    "strapi::body",
    "strapi::favicon",
    "strapi::public",
  ];
};

I tried to upgrade strapi to 4.25.2 but still no luck.
Expected behaviour :- if http://localhost:3000 is not in strapi's middleware origin list, it should get CORS error and should not be able to access strapi resources.
I've been trying different solution as i mentioned but none worked. If someone have any idea about this problem then kindly help!
Thanks!

Does a single origin work instead of an array?

@dargmuesli no, doesn't work.

to fix this bug you should upgrade @koa/cors to 3.4.3.related post.
remember to downgrade strapi to ver 4.23.0 and re install all package.
strapi under ver 4.23.0 is work correct. set strapi ver in package.json to 4.23.0

Tried this, didn't work.

you should remove node-module folder and package-lock.json.

replace origin: [
'http://localhost:3000'
]
strapi under ver 4.23.0 is work correct.
set strapi ver in package.json to 4.23.0

run npm install.

Hey, tried with 4.23.0, still the same, not working.

are you remove node module and lock.json?
are you replace origin: env... by origi: ['http://localhost:3000']?
koa version is 3.4.3?
canyou share your package.json?
and middleware
